# In python DEAP package, why a function can be called from a module which dose not have such function?

Tags: python, class, object, deap

I have just started to use the DEAP package in python. Following the tutorial, I can't understand this statement:

```
toolbox.register("cross",tools.cxTwoPoint)
```

I understand that `tools.cxTwoPoint` is to call the `cxTwoPoint` function. However, I checked the source code, the `cxTwoPoint` function is not within `tools` module, and it is a defined function within `crossover.py`. Also, I didn't find any statement in `tools.py` which may relate to `crossover.py` or `cxTwoPoint`.

Can someone help me? Many many thanks!!!

Comment: It is in deap.tools.mutation. Which gets importet into the deap.tools namespace. (https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/deap/tools/mutation.py)

Comment: Thanks for your information. And I also wonder there is a `tools.py` in benchmark folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tools.py` is used for benchmarking the algorithm. As we can seen from `__init__.py`, there is a statement `from .crossover import *` which means import all of the functions in the `crossover` module where located same directory as `__init__.py`. This gives you a easy way to access these functions in other files. And `__init__.py` are required to make Python trent the directories as containing packages as answered in:[What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for).